# How change cell stroke color

Tags: mxgraph

I am trying to dynamically change the border color of some of my shapes based on a cell's custom attribute, following is my code:

```
        var cells = graph.getChildCells();
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            var cell = cells[i];
            if (cell != null && ....) {
               var style=cell.getStyle();                       
               console.info('style='+style);
               style=style+mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR+"=red";
               cell.setStyle(style);
               console.info('style='+style);
            }
         }
```

In the browser's console I see:

> style=ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;rotation=40;
>   style=ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;rotation=40;strokeColor=red

but nothing happen. Is it the right approach ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer by myself ;-) Following is the working code to change the stroke color without modify other settings/styles of the shape:

```
var style=graph.getModel().getStyle(cell);
var newStyle=mxUtils.setStyle(style,mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR,'red');
var cs= new Array();
cs[0]=cell;
graph.setCellStyle(newStyle,cs);
```

I think it is little bit *tricky* compared to what it does but I didn't find better API than these.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way.

```
graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR, 'red', [cell])
```

Check mxGraph documentation [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.setCellStyles)